# How do I set the permissions so all users can read and write my repository?

Tags: git, permissions

I want to create a git repository and allow all users to have access to it. As per a recommendation in another question, I tried initializing it by:

```
git init --shared=0777
```

This allows other users to give a `git status` `git log` and `git branch`. However, if I ever try to commit anything on a branch as another user, this is the error message I get:

```
fatal: could not open '.git/COMMIT_EDITMSG': Permission denied
```

Any advice?

Comment: Does the user have linux permissions to edit and create files in the git directory?

Comment: Yes, the permission on the files are CHMOD 777.

Comment: Could they have their own repositories, then push to the shared repository? Then noone will ever need to commit directly to the shared repo.

Comment: Shared repositories should be bare, and should be only used to push to and fetch from them.

Comment: Douglas, I'm really new to git. So I didn't quite get that. Could you please explain further? ...

Answer (score 1):

I think you are suffering from a kind of SVN syndrome.  In git, each user has their own repo which is cloned from the "central" repo and they push and pull from the "central" repo, which, as Philipp points out, should be bare (when you create it, do git --bare init).  That repo should be shared, of course, but only so that people can push and pull from it.  They should not be making commits in it.  In fact, if it is a bare repo, then they are unable to make commits as there is no checked out working tree.

I'd really recommend reading some of the literature on the git website, specifically the sections/chapters about repos and how they relate to each other.

Comment: Yes, I also think that you need to use `git --bare init`

Comment: Thanks siride, I'll look em up!